# Handling elements child elements using async/await in Cucumber JS with Protractor returning no results

Tags: javascript, async-await, protractor

I am trying to automate a pretty trivial scenario where I have to get the text inside multiple `li` child elements of a `ul` elements and compare it against a given array. I am using Protractor with Cucumber JS and using `async/await` to manage promises.

My scenario HTML looks something like this

```
       <div class="some-class">
          <ul class="some-ul-class">
               <li>
                <span>Heading1: </span>
                <span class="some-span-class> Value of Heading 1</span>
               </li>
               <li>
                <span>Heading2: </span>
                <span class="some-span-class> Value of Heading 2</span>
               </li>
               <li>
                <span>Heading3: </span>
                <span class="some-span-class> Value of Heading 3</span>
               </li>
               <li>
                <span>Heading4: </span>
                <span class="some-span-class> Value of Heading 4</span>
               </li>
               <li>
                <span>Heading5: </span>
                <span class="some-span-class> Value of Heading 5</span>
               </li>
```

I need to get the values of the first span element i.e the `Heading1`, `Heading2` texts.  I saw a lot of approaches in SO, but none of them have resulted in a solution. Most of the solutions do not have `async/await` implemented and if I try them, the code doesn't do what it is intended to do.

Examples I've referred : [Protractor Tests get Values of Table entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34135713/protractor-tests-get-values-of-table-entries)
[Protractor : Read Table contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29501976/protractor-read-table-contents)

If I try using the `map` function inside the `async` block, but that resulted in a `ECONNREFUSED` error, and hence has been suggested not to do so [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/4706).

Would appreciate if someone can guide me towards a solution on this one.

Comment: Please show your `async` code, since that's where the issue lies. I'm going to go out on a limb and link [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one should work for you:

```
const elements = $$('.some-span-class');
const expected = [];
const elementsLength = await elements.count();
for (let i = 0; i < elementsLength; i += 1){
    const text = await elements.get(i).getText();
    expected.push(text);
}
```

When you do with `async/await` you should check what protractor method api returns, for example `$$` return an `ElementArrayFinder` and does not require await, while `getText` and `count` returns [`!webdriver.promise.Promise`](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.count) and require `await` statement first.

Answer (score 0):

You can shortage @Lunin Roman's answer:

```
const elements = $$('.some-span-class');
const textFromElements = elements.getText();
```

`textFromElements` is promise of string[]. When you resolve a promise:

`textFromElements.then((result) => {
console.log(result)
)})`

you should get an array of results.